# Interface Builder doesn't show objects

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, xcode6

I'm working with storyboards in **XCode 6.1.1** and my deployment target is set to 7.0 for an **iPhone Application**.

I was working with a scene weeks ago and when I got to make some other changes I realized that objects doesn't show up on IB and in document outline the objects appear with opacity (check screenshots), but when I run my application on device everything seems normal.

Any idea on what could be happening? I'll appreciate some help please, thanks!

http://i1299.photobucket.com/albums/ag68/nicowez/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202015-02-16%20a%20las%2011.22.41_zpspe1scbm4.png

http://i1299.photobucket.com/albums/ag68/nicowez/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202015-02-16%20a%20las%2011.23.00_zps6ukcuhdu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you set "size classes" incorrectly. For example, when you design a controller with a specific size class set and then you change the class to a different one.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan, this solved the problem! I had the scene with w/Any h/Any changed it to iPhone Portrait (w/Any h/Regular) and it worked!